# Select * Where Date is Today And Order Random limit 10

Tags: mysql

I Have Been thinking of the way to do this for almost a week now.

- I need to select data from MySQL database where date created is today and limit by 10
- If there is no data created today selection will be random and limit by 10
- If data created today is less than 10, it should select them and random the rest,
  For example: if 3 rows of data are created today, they should be selected first and random the 7 remaining without considering date.

Comment: OK. And what did your week of thoughts produce? Surely a bit more than just this list of requirements? What have you tried? Where are you stuck, precisely? We're happy to help people with their code here, but please don't request us to write the whole thing for you, most of us find that a bit presumptuous. We'd expect you to demonstrate you've made a genuine effort before asking for the free time of others. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make three different queries and combine their data with `UNION` and apply limit on `UNION` and on individual queries as well. Please keep the order same in which you need the data. This should resolve your problem easily.

Here is example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT 10
    UNION
    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT 10
    UNION
    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT 10
) as something LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Reading the Q I think two queries should be enough; date today and date not today.